# MYSQL TIMEDIFF function not working for long date

Tags: mysql, datetime

Mysql Timediff function is not working for me for long date.. Actually i need to get the time difference between date_time field to now()

so i used this query

```
SELECT `date_time`,now(),timediff(`date_time`,now()) FROM `table_datetime`
```

I have two rows

date_time
2011-04-25 17:22:41
2011-06-14 17:22:52

my result is
[image]

Here first row result is changing but not for second one this one always return

```
838:59:59
```

constantly ... Why its not giving correct result

Thanks for help !

Answer (score 11, accepted):

instead of `TIMEDIFF` use `DATEDIFF` with `EXTRACT`

```
SELECT DATEDIFF('2011-06-14 17:22:52', NOW()) * 24
+ EXTRACT(HOUR FROM '2011-06-14 17:22:52')
- EXTRACT(HOUR FROM NOW())
```

Thanks **@rekaszeru** for useful link

#### Alternate Solution ( get the difference in Seconds )

```
SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,NOW(),'2011-06-14 17:22:52');
```

**Reference**

#### [EXTRACT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_extract)

#### [TIMESTAMPDIFF](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timestampdiff)

Comment: HOW CAN I GET difference in seconds

Comment: +1 for alternative solusion that works very fine and really simple thanks

Comment: It might clearer as `hour('2011-06-14 17:22:52') - hour(now())`

Answer (score 4):

You should take a look at [this issue](http://www.microshell.com/database/mysql/getting-around-mysql-timediff-maximum-value-of-8385959/), and find a solution knowing those things

Comment: It's much better to answer the question directly then to link to an external article that could disappear at any time.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative solution for this problem is writing a user defined function. Please keep in mind, the return value is no longer a time-object but a string. So in MySQL you can't use it for further calculation:

```
DELIMITER $$

DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS `big_time_diff`$$

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` FUNCTION `big_timediff`(s_start VARCHAR(20), s_end VARCHAR(20)) RETURNS TEXT CHARSET latin1
BEGIN
    DECLARE s_hour VARCHAR(20);
    DECLARE s_rest VARCHAR(20);

    SET s_hour = ABS(TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR, s_end, s_start));
    SET s_rest = TIME_FORMAT(TIMEDIFF(s_start, s_end), ':%i:%s');

    RETURN INSERT(s_rest, LOCATE('-', s_rest) + 1, 0, IF(LENGTH(s_hour) > 2, s_hour, LPAD(s_hour, 2, 0)));
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Thanks! The big_time_to_sec: DELIMITER $$ DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS big_time_to_sec$$ CREATE DEFINER=root@localhost FUNCTION big_time_to_sec(big_time VARCHAR(20)) RETURNS INTEGER(11) BEGIN DECLARE s_hour_varchar VARCHAR(20); DECLARE s_hour_integer INTEGER(11); DECLARE s_seconds INTEGER(11); SET s_hour_varchar = REGEXP_SUBSTR(big_time, '[0-9]+'); SET s_hour_integer = CAST(s_hour_varchar AS INTEGER); SET s_seconds = s_hour_integer * 3600 + MINUTE(big_time) * 60 + SECOND(big_time); RETURN s_seconds; END$$ DELIMITER ;